# How to enable intellisense in VSCode for arguments passed to a Javascript function in a Node.js app?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

In my Node.js app I have my router defined in a separate js module:

```
    var routes = function (express) {
        var categoryRouter = express.Router();
        ..stuff being done..
        return categoryRouter;
    };
    module.exports = routes;
```

My main app.js passes express which comes from require('express'). How do I get intellisense for express within my routes above?
I know that if I were to use a simple type e.g. 'string' I could go with JSDoc as follows:

```
    /**
    * @param {string} paramA
    */
    var func= function (paramA) {
        .....
    };
```